# Accessing attributes in C++ through getters-setters

Tags: java, c++

Hi I have background in Java and currently learning C++. In Java it is not advisable to access the instance attributes directly, instance attributes are made private and accessed through getters-setters. Is it also advisable to create something like JavaBean in C++? Or is this not a common thing in the C++ lingo? If not, why isn't it advisable to create getters-setters in C++ to access instance attributes?

Comment: you could always use the Qt approach to getter/setters on C++

Comment: @AbiusX: can you describe what you feel are the hallmarks of that approach?

Comment: the name as the getter and set+name as the setter : e.g x() and setX()

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.  A little bit less boilerplate, at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really a general OO design question rather than a language question. Personally, I follow the school of thought "if you have many getters and mutators, your class design has a flaw". Public interface of a class is behavior, not its internal structure or some model of such structure. But of course it's just one point of view, and it is completely language-agnostic.

One thing that C++ discourages are "setters". Since well-written C++ classes are fully functional after the constructor runs (see "Scope-Bound Resource Management") any sort of post-construction "setting" goes against this language's best practices.

Comment: So does that mean you have to have several constructors depending on what attributes you want to pass in to the constructor?

Comment: Yes, if there are several ways to construct an object, you might need several constructors. The idea is that a constructor **fully** constructs an object into a valid state, not that you should adjust it afterwards. If you are just collecting a bunch of data, you can use a struct instead of a class.

Answer (score 4):

Don't create getters & setters "by default".  Create classes that encapsulate functionality, ideas, algorithms, and so on.  Don't make classes that are just a bunch of fields, or if you do, just declare them as `struct`s and admit that's what they are: a bunch of related data tied together without much if any encapsulation (which is fine in many cases).

There are exceptions to every rule, so you'll end up with a handful of getters & setters eventually, but it's not useful in most applications to have more than say one or two per class (very rough guess).

Edit to note: this is just my opinion, and I haven't seen your particular code.  Maybe you need hundreds of getters and setters.  I just happen to doubt it.  I hope the down-voters will offer a comment with some rationale.

Answer (score 3):

Using getters/setters is good advice for *any* OO driven language so yes, you *should* protect your internal data members via the properly exposed methods.

A nice byproduct of the C++ language is that those getters/setters will probably end of being inlined which means it's just as fast as accessing the members directly, only more safe.

Comment: I don't agree that it's "more safe" - I would say it is more future-proof.

Comment: You can disagree but accessors methods will be safer. You can return const references or copies with getters or make setters private to prevent external changes but in the end you are "protecting" your member variables from being mangled by whatever is using the class.

Comment: That's true if you are not writing a setter for each getter, I'll give you that (and I think doing so would be for the best).  But the way you phrased it "getters/setters" seemed to me to imply that they would tend to come in pairs.  If your answer just said "getters" I'd be more inclined to agree with it (even though it goes against my particular answer).

Comment: Python is an OO language, but it is not advisable to create getters-setters in Python classes.

Comment: Eh, it's built into the language as decorated accessors http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property

Answer (score -1):

Getters/Setters are part of object oriented programming. Since C++ lacks properties (which are the only way to get the equivalent of getters/setters), there's really no other way to get that functionality in C++.

So go for it.

Comment: It is really too bad that C++ doesn't have properties as C# does, isn't it?  That's one of the few things I really miss from C#.